# How to access "context.Rule.Member" in FluentValidation version 10?

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

Previously I was using Fluent validation version 8 and used "context.Rule.Member" in custom validators. Like

```
var groupAttribute = context.Rule.Member.GetCustomAttribute<GroupAttribute>();


if (context.Rule.Member.DeclaringType != entity.GetType() && context.Rule.Member.DeclaringType != entity.GetType().BaseType)
            {
                var propertyInfos = new List<PropertyInfo>();
                var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)((MemberExpression)context.Rule.Expression.Body).Expression;

                do
                {
                    propertyInfos.Insert(0, (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member);
                    memberExpression = memberExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;
                }
                while (memberExpression != null);

                foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
                {
                    instance = propertyInfo.GetValue(instance);
                }
            }

var lengthAttribute = context.Rule.Member.GetCustomAttribute<LengthAttribute>();
```

I have updated Fluent Validation 10 and I am not getting this Rule Directly. Someone Please help me to archive the same. Thanks in advance.